# Javascript in Wordpress widget works only on Home page

Tags: javascript, wordpress

I would like to use my widget in every pages, but that works only on home page.
I'm still in local for the moment. I'm writing my script in footer.php before the end of body like that :

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="wp-content/themes/twentyfourteen/js/formlist.js"></script>
```

I've seen that when I'm not on home page, when I inspect with developper tools, my script .js is red and not well imported. How can I make that ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to correctly enqueue your Javascript in your theme, i.e. something like this:

```
  function theme_name_scripts() {
        wp_enqueue_style( 'style-name', get_stylesheet_uri() );
        wp_enqueue_script( 'script-name', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/example.js', array(), '1.0.0', true );
    }

add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'theme_name_scripts' );
```

There are other methods, depending on if your script uses the main jQuery library and other considerations. See [Function Reference/wp enqueue script « WordPress Codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_enqueue_script) for information on all the ways to use `wp_enqueue_style`.

And use your Dev Tools to check for errors and correct loading.

Comment: Thanks, perfect! Don't forget to add : add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'theme_name_scripts' );

Answer (score -1):

Try calling your script like this:

`<script src="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri();?>/js/formlist.js"></script>`

If you are on your home page, `wp-content/themes/twentyfourteen...` may work just fine. But say you're on `yoursite.com/about` then it thinks the URL for the javascript file is `yoursite.com/about/wp-content/themes/twentyfourteen...`

Make sense?

Comment: Using wp_enqueue_script() is a much better way to add scripts in WordPress.